# Does de-listing an app on AppStore Connect make it's name available for use again?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

> Yes, I'm aware a new bundle ID means a new listing in the store. That's actually what we want - a clean break. It makes sense for our use case. It also gives us the opportunity to correct our bundle ID, which was inconsistent between our products and was using a legacy product name, thereby causing confusion.

I have an existing AppStore Connect app, *A*. I'm trying to replace it with a completely new implementation of the app, *B*, that has the same name but a different bundle ID. My intention was to get *B* completely ready in Connect, de-list *A*, then publish *B*. However, Connect is not allowing me to create the app for *B*:

[image]

I'm therefore trying to understand my options. I've looked at simply renaming *A* first, but that appears to require a new build of *A*:

[image]

I desperately wish to avoid this because because building *A* is very time-consuming and finicky to get working (legacy tech, nearly no automation). I therefore thought maybe the best approach would be:

1. Release *B* with a slightly different name
2. De-list *A* when we're ready
3. Re-publish *B* with a corrected name

Alternatively, with permission from the business, I could:

1. De-list *A* now
2. Register *B* using the same name

However, in both cases it is unclear to me whether de-listing an app will make its name become available for registering again. Can anyone confirm or deny this?